# How do I to shorten If else

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

My code looks like

```
private bool IsUserAditya(string username)
{
  return username == "Aditya"? true : false;
}
```

Can I shorten it further?

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: `return username == "Aditya";`

Comment: and even shorter: `return username=="Aditya"` - Still purposeless :-)

Comment: With VS2015 `bool IsUserAditya(string username) => username == "Aditya";`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I shorten it further?

Yes, a little bit

`return username == "Aditya";`

Any comparison in C# returns a `bool`, so no need to use the conditional operator.

Answer (score 3):

```
private bool IsUserAditya(string username)
{
    return username == "Aditya";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly related to shortening (properly even longer), but if you're comparing an input from a user, such as a username, use `string.Equals` which takes a `StringComparison` object:

```
private bool IsUserAditya(string username)
{
    return username.Equals("Aditya", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be `private bool IsUserAditya(string username)
{
    return username.Equals("Aditya", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
}` ? missing username.

Comment: @hdoghmen Doesn't matter, they're interchangeable

Answer (score 0):

Even shorter...

```
private bool IsUserAditya(string u){return u=="Aditya";}
```

but that only "shortens" the source code. Generated binary will be same size.